# Free ASN.1 Viewer and Editor

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, programming, file-format

I am trying to specify a binary file format and I like to have the code generated for multiple languages, like C++, C# etc. so that file exchange works flawlessly. For that to be successful, the file format also needs to be aware of endianness.

It looks like [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1) has all I need. While there is a [list of tools](https://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/asn1/Pages/Tools.aspx), I can hardly decide on which one to start with, so I'm asking you for recommendations. Which ASN.1 toolset have you used to successfully define a file format or protocol?

Requirements:

- Editor for defining the ASN.1 syntax, ideally with syntax highlighting and squiggly lines like modern programming environments have
- Decoding capability: Live preview of a binary file with the syntax I am editing
- Encoding capability: Create an empty binary file and let me populate it
- Code generation: generate C++ and C# code to read and write the file
- gratis, not necessarily open source, but open source is preferred
- works on Windows (10 in particular)

Comment: ASN.1 is to my experience mostly used in a professional environment and thus free tools are not so common. If you are not bound to ASN.1 I would recommend to first take a look onto alternatives with better free tooling support like Protobuf.

Comment: @Robert: I'm currently looking into Protobuf. Unfortunately the C++ code doesn't compile yet :-(